# passing enum in constructor as an argument

Tags: c++, enums, arguments

Enumeration is declared as follow in global scope,  PSLGVertex::PSLGVertex() constructor complains about the last argument that its "PSLGVertexType' is not a class or namespace"

What am I doing wrong here ?

```
enum PSLGVertexType {
REFLEX_VERTEX,
CONVEX_VERTEX,
MOVING_STEINER_VERTEX,
MULTI_STEINER_VERTEX,
RESTING_STEINER_VERTEX,
OTHER_VERTEX
};
```

Constructor

```
PSLGVertex::PSLGVertex() : mark(false), oriPosition(0, 0), speed(0, 0), 
startTime(0.0),firstin(NULL), firstout(NULL),type(PSLGVertexType::OTHER_VERTEX)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using `PSLGVertexType::`, which tells the compiler that `PSLGVertexType` is a class/struct or a namespace, but it's neither.

Use plain `OTHER_VERTEX`.

Comment: Yes I've tried this one also but compiler complains "class 'PSLGVertex' does not have any field named 'OTHER_VERTEX'" I really don't understand why compiler looks in the class definitions to find the enum actually its defined in the global scope in the header file rather than in the class body. Isn't it weird?

Comment: It's not weird, because the class name is the current innermost scope, so that's where the compiler looks first, before gradually "peeling off" the enclosing scopes. Anyway, you say the enum is in the global namespace, so what happens if you say `::OTHER_VERTEX`?

Comment: Again its a error, it leads to some unintelligible errors by compiler generally at these incidents its better to trust intuition rather than compiler output. BTW I noticed that this type(PSLGVertexType::OTHER_VERTEX) is "type" variable which is PSLGVErtexType declared in the class public section, I thought that it was keyword or some typcasting but actually it is not. AFAIU in constructor it doesn't call any function but initializes some properties in class with that expression. So the question becomes how to assign to local variable a enum? Tried type =PSLGVertexType::OTHER_VERTEX

Comment: Tried type =PSLGVertexType::OTHER_VERTEX w/o success :(( complained error is : "error: expected '(' before '=' token"

Comment: @SonyaBlade: It appears that you do not understand how enums works, or C++'s type system. You wrote "this type(PSLGVertexType::OTHER_VERTEX)", and that just does not make sense. `PSLGVertexType` is a type, but `OTHER_VERTEX` is a value.

Answer (score 0):

In C++-03, `enum` members are placed in the enclosing scope. So don't say

```
 PSLGVertexType::OTHER_VERTEX
```

but rather just

```
 OTHER_VERTEX
```

In C++11, your code would be fine, as the members are placed in both the enclosing scope (for backward compatibility) and in the inner enum scope as well.

C++11 also has new *scoped enums*, which you can read about [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#Strongly_typed_enumerations).

Comment: Please check my previous answer it again raises the error I'm using MinGW with GCC 4.4 in QtCReator.